# doctrine 2 getting a collection from 2 relationships?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

i have 2 tables members and comments.. i successfully joing them to. so now, i can get an collection of all entries for any user. but i need to create anothewr table called 'followers' , where each user can follow each. therefore, now, i want to be able to get all comments from 1 user also the comments for the users he is following too. but dont know what way to approach to complete this relationship with this new table.

users entity:

```
namespace Entities\Members;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Member\MembersRepository")
 * @Table(name="Members")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Members extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="bigint",length=15)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(name="userid", type="bigint", length=26, nullable=true) */
    protected $userid;
    /** @Column(name="fname", type="string", length=255,nullable=true) */
    protected $fname;
    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Entities\Users\Wall", mappedBy="entry", cascade={"persist"}) */
    protected $commententries;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->commententries = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

comments entity:

```
 namespace Entities\Members;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Member\CommentsRepository")
 * @Table(name="comments")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Comments extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="bigint",length=15)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(name="userid", type="bigint", length=26, nullable=true) */

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Entities\Member\Member", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="userid", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entry;

}
```

this works, i can get all comments from users via:

```
$this->repo->findByUserid(3);  (userid = 3)
```

however, how can i add a 'following' table (just like twitter).  where one can follow other, and therefore, i would be able to not only, see user id-3 comments but other comments from other user he is following?

table called: followers:

```
  namespace Entities\Members;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Member\FollowersRepository")
 * @Table(name="followers")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Followers extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="bigint",length=15)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(name="userid", type="bigint", length=26, nullable=true) */

    protected ???;

    /**
     * @Many  ???
     * @JoinColumn(   ???
     */
    protected $???;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to create a relationship from Followers to Members.

Then create a EntityRepository for the Comments Entity in which you'll create a function like: getCommentsByUserIdIncludingFollowers($userId) in which you create a DQL query that returns the correct information/comments you need.

This would be the way I'd suggest.

Comment: what kind of relationship from followers to members ?

Comment: In the Followers entity I would create a ManyToMany relationship to Members. You probably want to have One follower to be able to follow multiple Members and have one member to have multiple followers.

See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: but if i do that, it will created a manay-many table, which shows the links between members and followers. so, how will that work.. how would i then attach the comments to this linked table?

Comment: You would have a comment from a member, but can then do a query where you select all comments from the current logged in person, including his/her follower's comments by using JOIN's in the query.

Maybe you would also have to look into the many-to-many relation in Member itself. As it seems you want another member to be following other members. So a member would have the $following Many-To-Many and also the $followers Many-To-Many as reverse.